# BigQuery: RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'})

Tags: python-3.x, google-bigquery, jwt

bigquery == 1.21.0
python 3.7.2
jupyter notebook (google colab)
The following code doesn't work.
Also, recreating the service account or updating the key does not work.
jwt is a weak authentication. Looking at the issues on github, google seems to close the issue on a regular basis.
How can I resolve this error and create a dataset?

````
key_path = '/content/project1-0000000-4b7861b26a6a.json'
from google.cloud import storage as gcs
from google.oauth2 import service_account

credential = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(key_path)

from google.cloud import bigquery

PROJECT = 'project1'
bq = bigquery.Client(project=PROJECT, credentials=credential)

dataset_id2 = "{}.tokyo".format(PROJECT)
dsinfo3 = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_id2)
dsinfo3.location = "asia-northeast1"
ds_tokyo = bq.create_dataset(dsinfo3, exists_ok=True)```

###The following error.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
RefreshError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-63783f194a3e> in <module>()
     14 dsinfo3 = bigquery.Dataset(dataset_id2)
     15 dsinfo3.location = "asia-northeast1"
---> 16 ds_tokyo = bq.create_dataset(dsinfo3, exists_ok=True)

12 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/google/oauth2/_client.py in _handle_error_response(response_data)
     58         error_details = json.dumps(response_data)
     59 
---> 60     raise exceptions.RefreshError(error_details, response_data)
     61 
     62 

RefreshError: ('invalid_grant: Invalid JWT Signature.', {'error': 'invalid_grant', 'error_description': 'Invalid JWT Signature.'})
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
````

Comment: Can you post the error returned in colab? I can't replicate this with my own key.

Comment: I displayed an error.

Comment: Did you see this? https://medium.com/google-cloud/jwt-json-web-tokens-errors-invalid-jwt-signature-8aab13703eb5